Why does OpenText Runtime error 1004 even though file can be imported by hand
With Excel 365 for MAC/OS I get error 1004 when trying to open a *.csv file using VBA OpenText.
I receive .csv files (semicolon delimiter) from my bank and want to automate importing the data into worksheets. To that end, I recorded a macro while importing one of the files. The recording produced the following little function:
    Public Function openSource(fileToOpen As String) As Excel.Workbook
    'Open the text file with semicolon delimiters

    Debug.Print fileToOpen
    Workbooks.OpenText FileName:= _
            fileToOpen, Origin:= _
            65001, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False _
            , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), _
            Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), _
            Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array( _
            16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Function
`

This crashes immediately with the feared 1004 code. I must admit that I can't make heads or tails of what is happening here. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

How are you calling the function? Which line is highlighted if you click Debug on the Error message?

The function (openSource) is called from here.             Dim CSVWorkbook As New Excel.Workbook
csvfile = "/Users/bobwilcox/Documents/DAB             Konten/Depot 2023/" & result(7)
Debug.Print csvfile
Set CSVWorkbook = openSource(csvfile)

but the debug.print command before the Opentext was executed and left /Users/bobwilcox/Documents/DAB Konten/Depot 2023/20230111.csv (the .csv file being imported)

What is the type of variable 'csvfile'? If it is Variant (which it will be if it isn't declared), then the function call will fail.

Thanks for the comment. csvfile is defined as string in the calling subroutine. The parameter in the called function (filetoopen) is also string. Public Function openSource(filetoopen As String) As Excel.Workbook

I cant see the end of the code, could you check it and edit in the post till the End Function

Thanks for your interest. I just added the End Function

With high probability it is not an UTF-8 coded file. Can you check it?

Try to open after delete the Origin: option and let Excel to define the coding.

Thanks for the tip. I deleted the Origin:. No more 1004. However, the semicolons did not act as separators. Everything (semicolons and data) is smashed together into a single column.  Any ideas?

Rename the csv file to txt, and call the function with this extension.

Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the semicolons still don't separate.

This works for me on Windows platform with same parameters, and i havent Mac.

I really think this might have something to do with the coding of my data. When I looked closer at the result, I saw that the semicolons were not recognised, but that commas in the data were causing column splits. I didn't notice it at first because the first rows don't have any commas. If I'm right that it's the coding, I'm stuck since I am a complete ignoramus about coding.
